# Document retention policies sharepoint foundation, any alternative?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

As we know we don't have document retention policies in SharePoint foundation 2013 and it's an enterprise feature.

Is there any alternative other then creating a timer job and go through hundreds, thousands for sites/libraries

or

Creating event receivers and manage retention polices in custom database ?

Answer (score 0):

In the timer job approach, you shouldn't have to loop through all items, just query the search service. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for a doc about using the rest api.